# How to let \animategraphics only need a shorten path by leveraging a \graphicpath-like command?

Tags: graphics, animate

Assume that I have a sub directory `Images` in which all image files of PDF type exists. Some PDF files have more than one page so I can animate them with `\animategraphics`. For any single-page PDF files, I just use `\includegraphics` to import them from with the `main.tex`.

The directory structure of my project is as follows.

```
...\MyDocuments\Projects\Project1\main.tex
...\MyDocuments\Projects\Project1\Images\image1.pdf
...\MyDocuments\Projects\Project1\Images\image2.pdf
```

If I specify `\graphicspath{{Images/}}`, I can use `\includegraphics{image1}` to simplify `\includegraphics{Images/image2}`.

My problem is how can we use `\animategraphics[...]{...}{image2}{}{}` to simplify `\animategraphics[...]{...}{Images/image2}{}{}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{Images/}}
```

should suffice.